# A serious bug of version JW player 6.x thumbnail tooltip bug on flash

Tags: flash, jwplayer, jwplayer6

This is a serious bug of version since JW player 6.0 until recent latest version on Flash. Someone reported this bug since the version 6.0 launched but this bug never fixed by their support.

It's hard to explain how the behavior of the bug, please hit the play button and mouseover the timeline after the video played to see the behavior of thumbnail tooltip at [here](http://jwplayerbugs.co.nf).

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, this issue is because of multiple sprites being uses for the tooltip thumbs. We recommend using one sprite for the time being, until this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , we should let jwplayer's javascript to build the html code.

Initilaize jwplayer with js, and use HTML5 video in html like this:

```
<center>            
    <video controls="controls" id="container" poster="http://www.example.com/yourvideothumbs/videothumb.jpg"  width="693" height="388">
            <source src="http://www.example.com/videos/jourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>                        
</center>
```

Javascript:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(android)/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(chrom)/) ){
    //wee must force flash video player in chrome, because mp4 video files is not supported yet in chrome's HTML5 video implementation.
    modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}];
}else{
    modes = [ {type: 'html5'},{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]swf/player.swf'}];
}

jwplayer("container").setup({                   
    'modes':modes,      
});
```

This worked me in all browsers. jwplayer can conform if is HTML5 supported or not.

Or the below with forced HTML4 implementation:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
       modes = [{type: 'flash', src:  '[JWPLAYERBASEDIR]/swf/player.swf'}], //force flashplayer for video
       image: "yourvideothumbs/videothumb.jpg", //poster image
       file: "videos/jourvideo.mp4",  //video file 
       height: "693", //set height in px
       width: "388" //set width in px
   });
```

And in setup you can set skin, controls, autostart anything you want: `http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player/`

Comment: Modes is not supported in JW Player 6 version.